# jain sip how to connect with WiFi in android

Tags: java, android, jain-sip

I am developing a softphone using jain sip which is about to complete except the following problem:
I am using [restcomm-android-sdk](http://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/JAIN%20SIP) on [android-jain-sip-ri-1.2.233.jar](https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/JAIN-SIP/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/jain-sip/m2/android-jain-sip-ri/target/android-jain-sip-ri-1.2.233-sources.jar)
and the problem is
let say two clients are *client A* and *client B*,

1. If *client A* and *client B* are using 3G/4G , then everything is working fine as they both can call each other and can here each others voice properly.
2. If *client A* is using 3G/4G network and *clent B* is on public WiFi then both can call each other but only *client A* can hear voice of *Client B*, *client B* cannot hear anything.

I think is something relating to routing and nat,
here is my android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

Could anyone please help in solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The NAT may be too restrictive in the public Wifi that you're using. 
Did you try on a non public wifi ?
Which SIP Server do you use ? Do you use [RestComm](http://www.telestax.com/restcomm-7-3-0-is-here/) as Server ?

To be sure a network capture aka wireshark trace would needed (on the client side - you can try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&hl=fr and on the server side too)

If that's the case (NAT too restrictive, STUN And TURN will need to be implemented on the Android client, planned on the roadmap). Another option if you use RestComm is to create a conferencing application and have both clients call the conferencing application to see if that helps.

Did you try with both clients on different public wifi networks ?

Comment: 2. I am using asterisk as PBX   3. I import the open source project and work upon him  [link](http://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/JAIN%20SIP)  4. i am not using conferencing application this is single one to one dial

Comment: 1. It seems this is a NAT issue (too restrictive) or the Public Wifi is too restrictive and block Media Packets.

Comment: 2. I don't have much experience with Asterisk, just make sure that Asterisk stays in the media path, that should help.but if you switch to RestComm (see http://www.telestax.com/rapid-telecom-application-development-with-restcomm-and-docker/), I can potentially help

Comment: [shark for root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&hl=fr)  gives output : syntax error:"can't execute root start up sequence. Do you have root? "on both public and non -public wifi

Comment: Asterisk stay in media path for sure, because when i am using another softphone or sip phone i.e. Zoiper, its work in public wifi also, means problem insists with my ip phone, yes its seems this is NAT issue(too restrictive) , can you lead me direction where i can solve this.

Comment: Would you like to do a guest blog post of your experience and the setup you just did on http://telestax.com/, if so contact us on info@telestax.com, we would very pleased to feature you there